# Obfuscating the php code before deploying on Cpanel?

Tags: php, php-7

Is there any way to obfuscate the PHP code before deploying on the cpanel?

Use case :

The reason I am asking this is because if I give someone a script that he/she wants to use on their cpanel , i dont want them to be able to make changes or steal the source code , i only want them to be able to use the script as is.

So is there a way to generate an obfuscated version of php which is able to run on cpanel ?

Comment: You can use paid services like ioncube

Comment: Keep the script on your own server and allow them to import it and reference call it at runtime only.